# Can I get return actual value if I use launch in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning Coroutines of Kotlin.

The Code A use `async` in the coroutines of Kotlin and I can use `.await()` on a deferred value to get its eventual result, so `one.await()` will return Int.

If I use `launch` in the coroutines, can I get the actual value just like `one.await()`?

**Code A**

```
val time = measureTimeMillis {
    val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
    val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
    println("The answer is ${one.await() + two.await()}")
}
println("Completed in $time ms")       

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulOne(): Int {
    delay(1000L) // pretend we are doing something useful here
    return 13
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulTwo(): Int {
    delay(1000L) // pretend we are doing something useful here, too
    return 29
}
```

Comment: Why would you? The whole point of the existence of these two things, `async` and `launch`, is that one is for computations that return a value and the other for work that produces side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [standard non-hacky] way to get the result from `launch`. This is the whole point of having `async`.

The 2 functions `launch` and `async` have precisely one difference, which is that `launch` is fire-and-forget, and `async` allows to wait for a result.

Therefore, there should be no reason for you to want to use `launch` over `async` unless you don't need the result, so the question is quite suprising.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `launch`, the "actual value" is `Unit` as you can see from [the signature](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html)

```
fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job (source)
```

so you don't even need to start it.

If you pass a lambda to `launch` as in

```
launch { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
```

it is really

```
launch { doSomethingUsefulOne(); Unit }
```

and the value of `doSomethingUsefulOne()` is thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **NO**

As you pointed out `async` and `await` will get you the result.

But `Launch` is used for a different purpose. Its purpose is to act as a **bridge** between Coroutine and NonCoroutine worlds.

Consider an example of a ViewModel whose coroutine world is controlled by `viewModelScope`

```
fun nonCoroutineWorldFunction() {
 ....
 ....
 viewModelScope.launch { 
   // runs in coroutine world
 }
 ....
 ....
 viewModelScope.launch { 
   // runs in coroutine world
 }


}
```

`Launch` can be considered something similar to `FIRE AND FORGET`. You just launch it to do its job rather than waiting for it to do its job

Comment: It can be used for that, but it's perfectly usable inside coroutine world as well.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. In this particular case, I was only trying to explain the difference between `async` and `launch`, where launch usually means fire and forget